# Generate XML from XSD repeatable elements

Tags: json, xml, xsd, generator

Whats the tool to generate xml from xsd and the generated xml should contain more than one entries for the repeatable elements? I tried out tools that are available on eclipse and some online tools like [xml-generator](http://xmlgrid.net/genXml.html), but none of these work. They all generate only one entry for the repeatable elements.

Note: I want to convert the generated xml to json, but the xml-json convertor treats the repeatable elements in the xml as an array only if it has more than one entry.

Answer (score 0):

Generating XMLs from XSD can be quite challenging, if only because what people expect to see may not be possible to be captured by an XSD.

[QTAssistant](https://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) has quite extensive features when it comes to sample XML creation.

The simplest (and dumbest) one (available by right clicking on the element in the graphical XSD visualizer) is still able to create two elements if the associated maxOccurs is greater than one.

[image: Sample XSD with Generate Sample XML File command]

However, the XML may be off: just because one may have named a field dateTime, it doesn't mean the generated text node will be a valid date time value, if the schema defined it as a string. The tool will also only create one of the choices (if your schema uses `xsd:choice`), etc.

[image: Sample XML with repeating elements]

QTAssistant can make use of additional metadata which gives the user ultimate control over the generated samples. It can even create thousands of XMLs by doing combinations captured using metadata items. (You should contact us on the support site if you're interested in these scenarios).

Regarding XML to JSON conversion, QTAssistant can also correctly convert XMLs to JSON for repeating fields. Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<fundamo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:common="http://www.myorg.com/xsd/gen_fin">
    <response>
        <common:code>code1</common:code>
        <common:description>description1</common:description>
    </response>
    <transaction>
        <transactionRef>transactionRef1</transactionRef>
        <dateTime>dateTime1</dateTime>
        <userName>userName1</userName>
    </transaction>
</fundamo>
```

The corresponding JSON is:

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": "code1",
        "description": "description1"
    },
    "transaction": [
        {
            "transactionRef": "transactionRef1",
            "dateTime": "dateTime1",
            "userName": "userName1"
        }
    ]
}
```

You may notice that transaction is an array, even if XML has only one of those elements. This conversion works for valid XMLs, as long as you have a defined XSD for all its content. For the past 2+ years we've been calling it "XSD-aware JSON conversion". It is also possible to define casing conversion strategies (e.g. change upper case to lower case since XML elements tend to be upper case, while JSON "people" prefer them lower case).

If you're in for a free tool or to write your own, I am sure you can use the free evaluation as a source of inspiration to address only the specific features you're interested in.